# Collections groupBy

Tags: elementquery

This feels like a really dumb one...when I'm grouping a collection, how do I loop over it?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().collect() %}
{% set groupBySection = entries.groupBy('section.handle') %}
{% for entry in groupBySection %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get nothing back. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you use [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby) (for Collections, Craft 4+ only) or Craft's [group filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#group) (for arrays), you'll get back an array where the keys are the thing you grouped by, and the values are nested arrays for each group. Therefore you'll need a nested loop to access your data. In a Twig loop, you can address the key and value separately like this:

```twig
{% set entriesGrouped = craft.entries().collect().groupBy('section.handle') %}

... alternatively without using collections, you could use the group filter like this:

{% set entriesGrouped = craft.entries().all()|group(entry => entry.section.handle) %}

{% for section, entries in entriesGrouped %}
    <h3>{{ section }}</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry }}</li>      
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! As expected, a silly one from me.